# Conditionally change font color - crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to make a text box conditionally invisible by tying it to the value of adjacent revenue column.. I tried using the formula - if command.revenue > 5000 then crgreen else crnocolor , in the font formula editor but it is not working. Need help in doing this the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should conditionally suppress the value instead of making it invisible; set the suppression formula for the textbox to

```
Command.Revenue > 5000
```

Comment: @Abey, I'm glad you green-checked LittleBobbyTables's response.  If you just changed the color of the textbox, the user could still see the underlying value by highlighting it.